# What are the best Deadlands Classic adventures (for beginners)?

Tags: published-adventures, deadlands-classic

My friends and I are working on starting a campaign in the Weird West of Deadlands Classic. We've never done Deadlands before, but we're otherwise RPG veterans. What would be some good adventures to start us off? I've already seen Night Train recommended on Reddit (with the further recommendation that the difficulty be turned down), though I don't know if that's for Classic or Reloaded.

Comment: You may have some success over at the official Pinnacle forum. [https://www.pegforum.com/]